# Weka "Use Training Set" in Test Option method for Java

Tags: java, weka

Anyone know what is this "Use training set" method in Weka for java programming? because this method I have googling quite number of time but none of the Weka forum have discuss about how to construct "Use training set" method in java programing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you use independent [test set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_set) for testing your trained classifiers. If you use this option, you test your trained classifier on your [train set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Training_set), giving over-fit results, which are grossly optimistic.

Read following [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19048/what-is-the-difference-between-test-set-and-validation-set) for more information.